# How to list YAML records based on categories?

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have a YAML database with data in the following format:

```
- product:
  name: Apples

- product:
  name: Grapes
```

How can I update it so each product is assigned to a category, then on my page I can have an unordered list the products under a category heading?

For example:

```
Fruit
  *Apples
  *Grapes

Vegetables
  *Tomatoes
  *Broccoli
```

I tried searching for an example of something like this, but couldn't find anything. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
- category:
  name: fruit

  - product:
    name: Apples

  - product:
    name: Grapes

- category:
  name: vegetables

  - product:
    name: Tomatoes

  - product:
    name: Broccoli
```

Comment: Can you clarify some more - do you want to use a different YAML database structure, or you want ruby to create the categorized structure?

Comment: I added an example of what I'd like to do, but I don't think it's valid YAML. Preferably, the category name would be listed once then all the records would be nested under it. I also need to generate the headings in the Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest two schemes, the first groups all products together:

```
products:
  - name: Apple
    type: Fruit

  - name: Grape
    type: Fruit

  - name: Tomato
    type: Vegetable

  - name: Brocoli
    type: Vegetable
```

The other scheme would be using on group for each type of product

```
fruits:
  - name: Apple

  - name: Grape

vegetable:
  - name: Tomato

  - name: Brocoli
```

To actually display this you would just load the yaml data with something like (forgive me if this has changed... it's been a while since I used yaml):

```
require 'yaml'
data = YAML.load_file('data.yml')
```

data is essentially just a ruby hash so you can display whatever you like by traversing it.

EDIT:

If the second option is what you want. Try the following:

```
require 'yaml'

data = YAML.load_file('data.yml')
data.each do |category, products|
  puts "#{category}"
  products.each do |product|
    puts "\t#{products}"
  end
end
```

Output should be:

```
fruits
     Apple
     Grape
vegetable
     Tomato
     Brocoli
```

If you want to output html, then modify it to something like:

```
require 'yaml'

data = YAML.load_file('data.yml')
data.each do |category, products|
  puts "#{category}"
  puts "<ul>"
  products.each do |product|
    puts "<li>#{products}</li>"
  end
  puts "</ul>"
end
```

You can see the differences to add the html formatting is very simple and you should be able to further modify this to your needs.

Comment: The second option is what @Zoolander wants.

Comment: Looks great, I'm just a Ruby n00b and am not sure how to create a heading for each type then list each product name in a grouped unordered list.

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. Typoed. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign a `category` attribute to each `Product`:

```
- name: Apples
  category: Fruit
- name: Grapes
  category: Fruit
- name: Tomatoes
  category: Vegetables
- name: Broccoli
  category: Vegetables
```

...and then load the data for all `Fruit`s:

```
require "yaml"
YAML.load("products.yml").select{ |product| product["category"] == "Fruit" }
# => [{"name"=>"Apples", "category"=>"Fruit"}, {"name"=>"Grapes", "category"=>"Fruit"}]
```